# Which IDE are CLISP Programmers using?

Tags: emacs, ide, slime, clisp

I noticed how SLIME (lisp development package for Emacs) does not come with a frame-source-location function for CLISP, so you can't automagically jump to a source location when inside the debugger. Given that, I figured CLISP users must be using some other IDE (though I guess IDE is a little bit misleading here, maybe they're just using a different Emacs package).

So what IDE/Emacs package are CLISP programmers using?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but every CLISP programmer I've known (including myself) has switched to SBCL because it's faster and compatible with SLIME. Unless you have a compelling reason for using CLISP you should consider switching.

Comment: I use SBCL also, with the CUSP plugin for Eclipse. This might not be much of an answer, since you are looking for CLISP, but it certainly works well for me, and SBCL is also a common lisp, so you aren't really changing that much.

Comment: Alright then, I just switched to SBCL. Makes me wonder about how many people are still using CLISP...

Comment: There is another question on this subject. Nelson suggests LispIDE there which supports CLISP. Check at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232486/best-common-lisp-ide/275565#275565

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Emacs and SLIME is still what those people use.

Comment: 3 years later, all I can do is agree :-)